# Which tables can I exclude from export?

Tags: database

I need to make a copy of my project for testing and developement. However, my database hoster is very weak and there are always gateway timeouts, so this time I try to only export and import the necessary tables.

I noticed that there are some very big tables:

[image]

Can I exclude their data and only export the structure or is the data essential for magento to work?

Which tables can I exclude which are essential?

---

### More infos

Database:

**innodb_lock_wait_timeout** is set to "240"

Comment: Does no one know it?

Answer (score 0):

Make a dump through SSH `mysqldump -u username -p dbname > db_dump.sql`.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I don't have the password, I can only access Phpmyadmin.